# Example 1-7 from The C Programming Language(version 2)

Tags: c

I am having trouble understanding the example 1.7 given in The C Programming Language. The main purpose of this example is to illustrate the use of functions in C. The book describes the following program as such, "Since C has no exponentiation operator like ** of Fortran, let us illustrate the mechanics of function definition by writing a function power(m,n) to raise an integer m to a positive power n. That is, the value of power(2,5) is 32. This function is not a practical exponentiation routine since it handles only positive powers of small integers, but it's good enough for illustration."
  This is the block of C code that follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int power(int m, int n);  /*function prototype */
int main() {
/* test power function */
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 10;++i)
    printf("%d %d %d\n",i,power(2,i),power(-3,i));
return 0;
}

/* power: raise base to the nth power;n >=0 */
int power(int base,int n) {
    int i , p;
    p = 1;
    for(i = 1;i <= n;++i) 
        p = p * base;
    return p;
 }
```

I understand everything up to the power function's code block. What is confusing me is that for loop. I am still learning C(obviously, i'm in the first chapter) but I come from JavaScript. So when I see this for loop I expect the `i` to need to be 'bound' to something for it to be of us in iteration(similar to the first for loop in the example). But the power function `returns p` after `p = p * base;`. It's not returning anything to do with `i`.  So to me, I think, what is the purpose of this for loop? I notice that if I comment out the for loop and remove the integer `i` then the numbers printed out do not increment except for the numbers within the previous for loop. To me, I expect the `int n` would need to increment. Not the `i`.

It appears to me that within the for loop that `n` is only being used as comparison to `i`. Is the purpose of the for loop in the power function only to execute `p = p * base` if `i <= n` is true? That can't be true because if that was then it would better be server with just an if statement and wouldn't need a `++i` to increment.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I suggest that you format your block of codes before complains arrive ...

Comment: I appreciate the advice. My bad, this is my first post and i wasn't thinking.

Comment: Hello, it is better to ask your questions in points and precisely.

Comment: Since the [JavaScript `for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) has essentially the same structure as a C11 `for` loop, it isn't obvious why you're having major mental stumbling blocks with the C version.

Comment: `i` inside the function is just a counter so that the algorithm can know when to stop counting. And that's it.

Comment: The code *could* very well use `--n` and count down to zero. Suppose the purpose here is to show how you can write a for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for-loop in the `power` function repeatedly multiplies (and updates) `p` by `base`. It does this `n` times -- `i` is the counter. If an if-statement were used, then you'd only get up to one multiplication.

Comment: Are you saying that the `p = p * base;` happens as many times until `i = n`?

Comment: Yes. Exactly: a while-loop is like an if-statement insofar as the body of the loop is executed if and only if the boolean expression in the parentheses is true; however, it does this until it is no longer true whereas an if-statement's body is run exactly 0 or 1 times (unless it is inside another loop).

Comment: Thank you so much for reading my rambling of a first post and giving such  a straight-forward reply. And so quickly. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you accept this as the answer if it resolved your doubt/problem. It encourages people :)

Comment: @SajithP  bc I did not realize that was a thing. Thank you for pointing that out to me.